# Eclipse RCP - prevent moving views to another folder (or just prevent moving)

Tags: view, eclipse-rcp

In Eclipse IDE we can see that some views cannot be moved to another folder, e.g. view "Package" cannot be moved to editor tabs. So, how can i prevent moving view to another folder?

I tried to prevent moving view at all, but I need to be able to close tabs, so the

```
layout.setFixed(true);
```

is not the solution. I have multiple view in my folder, and following

```
folder = layout.createFolder(FOLDER_ID, IPageLayout.TOP,
    ratio, editorArea);
folder.addPlaceholder(View.ID + ":viewSecondaryID*");

String id = View.ID;
String secondaryId = Integer.toString(View.getCurrentId());
folder.addView(id + ":" + secondaryId); 

IViewLayout view = layout.getViewLayout(id + ":" + secondaryId);
view.setMoveable(false);
```

doesn't work. Does anyone have any ideas here?

Answer (score 0):

Try to define it in the plugin.xml.

> > **moveable** - optional attribute that specifies wether the view should be moveable. If absent it will be moveable.

Example:

```
  <view
  class="org.eclipsercp.hyperbola.ContactsView"
  icon="icons/groups.gif"
  moveable="false"
  id="org.eclipsercp.hyperbola.views.contacts"
  name="Contacts"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, but for some reason it doesn't work, views still can be moved. Also it doesn't work with any other views